# Javascript OOP class object inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, instance, prototypal-inheritance

The Javascript code below outputs:
Employee {#name: "sheila", #gender: "female", #manager: Employee, #job: Job}

How do I fix it so that it outputs:
Employee {#name: "sheila", #gender: "female", #manager: "pierre", #job: "software engineer"}

Not sure if there is a hoisting problem.
Which lines do I fix so that #manager is "pierre" and #job is "software engineer"?

```
class Person{                   
    #name;              
    #gender;                

    constructor(name, gender) {             
        this.#name = name;          
        this.#gender = gender;          
    };              
                    
    setName(name) {             
        this.#name = name;          
    };              
                    
    getName() {             
        return this.#name;          
    };              
                    
    setGender(gender) {             
        this.#gender = gender;          
    }               
                    
    getGender() {               
        return this.#gender;            
    };              
}                   
                    
class Employee extends Person{                  
    #manager;               
    #job;               
                    
    constructor(name, gender, manager, job) {               
        super(name, gender);            
        this.#manager = manager;            
        this.#job = job;            
    };              
                    
    setManager(manager) {               
        this.#manager = manager;            
    }               
                    
    getManager() {              
        return this.#manager;           
    }               
                    
    setJob(job) {               
        this.#job = job;            
    }               
                    
    getJob() {              
        return this.#job;           
    }               
}                   
                    
class Job {                 
    #title;             
                    
    constructor(title) {                
        this.#title = title;            
    };              
}                   
                    
const softwareEngineer = new Job("software engineer");                  
                    
const keith = new Employee("keith", "male");                    
                    
const pierre = new Employee("pierre", "male");                  
                    
const sheila = new Employee("sheila", "female", keith, softwareEngineer);                   
                    
sheila.setManager(pierre);                  
console.log(sheila);
```

Comment: Well the "job" property is an object. You can give it a `.toString()` method so that when it's logged it can produce a string to your liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you print the type of the Object instead of the value. You need a toString function for Job and Manager to print the value instead of type, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString